# Submitting a form from elm code

Tags: elm, frames, forms, http-post

I have this frameset division:

```
<frameset cols="*,200">
<frame name="main" src="/main.html">
<frame name="sidebar" src="/sidebar">
</frameset>
```

And this is my `elm` logic is inside `main.html`:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
      Html.form [method "POST", action "/sidebar", target "sidebar" ]
  [ input [ type_ "text" ,placeholder "user"] [],
  input [ type_ "password", placeholder "password"] [],
  input [ type_ "submit" ,value "Submit"] []
  ]
```

I want to invoke the form submission from my code.

How can I trigger the submission of the form from `elm` ?

**EDIT:**

This is what I came up with, pretty ugly:

```
submit2frame frm = attribute "onclick" ("javascript:this.form.target=" ++ frm ++ ";this.form.action=\"/" ++ frm ++ "\";this.form.submit();")
```

Comment: Disregarding elm, how would you normally invoke form submission?  Wouldn't you have a set of fields that you wanted to submit and then a button that the user hit to send that data to the server?  I have never used `Html.form`, but it seems to me that you would store your form values in your model and then when you hit `Submit` this would trigger an `onToggle` event that would fire [`http.post`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/1.0.0/Http#post). I may be missing something though...

Comment: Can you post the full code using the [elli app](https://ellie-app.com/new)? (or at least a version with just the form and what you are trying to do?

Comment: Note that since frames are involved, triggering a `from.submit()` would cause the target frame to reload. This is a different behavior than firing an asynchronous post request.

Comment: Why not something like this? https://ellie-app.com/33xPYXv7ta1/1

Comment: maybe I missunderstood, but I don't see a form submission in the code

Comment: The form submission code would be fired after the message `SubmitForm`.  Instead of `update` returning just the `model`, it would return a tuple - `(Model, Msg)`.  Then we would add another message to the effect of `PostData` which would post the data (or something like that).  I do not have the post there because it would not compile if it was.  This simply demonstrates how the model changes with the input changing and what happens when `Submit` is pressed; adding the post code here is quite trivial.

Comment: Try this - https://ellie-app.com/33xPYXv7ta1/15. The message function to submit the data doesn't do anything because I have no idea where to post it.  You would want to add your own `Http.post` and `Http.send` logic to create the command that would fire the submission.  Also, you would use the `PostData` to handle the response.